# How do I make the same crop from two images in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I have two images that were taken at the exact same spot by at a different time. I want to make a side by side comparison image to show the differences of a zoomed in crop of the image. How do I do this in photoshop? How do I make sure that the two crop sizes are the same and at the exact pixel location between the two images?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to position the two images above each other in separate layers, set the upper layer to 50% transparency. You can then manually align the layers and crop the images to a specific size. First save the image with the lower layer visible, then the upper.

There's probably a better way to do it, but if you need to do it only once, it's probably not worth putting effort into.

Comment: I'd do a variation on this, almost the same.  Just wouldn't involve cropping specifically.  Same deal.  Start with the first image, add the second image in a new layer.  Use transparency to confirm the images are aligned.  Create the selection area, but instead of cropping, copy the area from the first layer and paste it into a new image.  Then using that same selection area, change to the other layer, copy and paste that into another new image.